# How to find the most similar item from within a set to my test item depending on certain criteria?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, grouping, similarity

I have a dataset of a group of players and various stats. Here's a sample of the file.

```
                      name      nat   tm  age        pos   cm  kg    app  \
0          Héctor Bellerín  Arsenal   es   21  D(R),M(R)  177  74     36   
1          Mathieu Debuchy  Arsenal   fr   31       D(R)  177  76      2   
2          Mathieu Flamini  Arsenal   fr   32       M(C)  178  67  12(4)   
3                Petr Cech  Arsenal   cz   34         GK  196  90     34   
4  Alex Oxlade Chamberlain  Arsenal  eng   23     M(CLR)  180  70  9(13)   

    min  G  A yel red  spG   pa% aerWon moM  tac  int fouls offW clear drbP  \
0  3240  1  5   3   -  0.4  85.7    1.1   1  1.6  1.8   0.5    -   2.4  0.6   
1   144  -  -   -   -  0.5  74.7      3   -  4.5  1.5   1.5    -   0.5  0.5   
2  1089  -  -   3   -  0.4  86.8    0.8   -  1.9  2.2   1.1  0.1   1.6  0.8   
3  3060  -  -   -   -    -    59    0.2   2    -    -     -    -     1    -   
4   925  1  -   -   -    1  82.5    0.4   -    1  0.5   0.5    -   0.4  0.5   

  blcks ownG   KP  drb fouled cOff disp unsT  avgP crosses longB thrB   season  
0   0.2    -  0.7  1.8    0.2    -    1  0.9  46.9     0.5   0.9  0.1  2015-16  
1     -    -  0.5  0.5    0.5    -    2  0.5  39.5       -     1    -  2015-16  
2   0.8    -  0.2  0.1    0.2    -  0.3  0.3  39.3     0.1   1.1    -  2015-16  
3     -    -    -  0.1    0.1    -    -    -  25.1       -   8.2    -  2015-16  
4   0.2    -  0.9  1.7    0.6  0.1  1.1  1.1    20     0.4   1.2    -  2015-16  
>>>
```

I want to find the player most similar to `Hector Bellerin` (index = 0), with respect to the columns `tac`, `int`, `blcks`, `unsT`, `cOff`, and `spG`.
How do I acheive that using a) any means at all and b) using certain clustering or grouping mechanisms? I have known people to do similar things using Euclidean distances but I'm not entirely sure about the methodology.

Comment: The general idea is to consider players as vectors of features (tac, int, ...), then find a metric to evaluate the similarity (or dissimilarity/distance) between vectors (players). Do you have a precise goal?

Comment: I just want to find the top ten similar players to Bellerin as well as learn a bit about machine learning in the process so no, nothing very precise @sentence

Answer (score 1):

each player here is a vector, you can perform any vector similarity

Euclidean Distance for your problem,

```
player = tac + int + blcks + unsT + cOff + spG
distance(player_1, player_2) = sqrt (sqr(tac_1-tac_2) + sqr(int_1-int_2) + .....)
```

Comment: Could you recommend a primer for learning more about vectors?

Comment: @Abhishek follow this article http://dataaspirant.com/2015/04/11/five-most-popular-similarity-measures-implementation-in-python/ , it discusses some vector similarity methods

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is called K-means

K-means is a clustering algorithm that tries to partition a set of points into K sets (clusters) such that the points in each cluster tend to be near each other. It is unsupervised because the points have no external classification.

see example here : https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-k-means-clustering-in-machine-learning-6a6e67336aa1

Simple example how to apply this method:

```
   from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
   import numpy as np
   # Your dataset 
   X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
          [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])

   # Devide your  set into clusters by applying Kmeans algorithm
   kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)

   # Examine the labels ( We  decide to divide your dataset into 2  
   #clusters n_clusters=2)
   kmeans.labels_
   array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Based on  the labels you can see which samples(players) have similarities.

Comment: Do I have to train the model on some of the data first?

Comment: Yes you have to divide your dataset for train and test ( 70%/30%) usually .  Yes exactly you have to train it firstly .

Comment: .                                                                                   
fit(X[, y, sample_weight])    - Compute k-means clustering.                            
Where you train the model based on your training dataset 
predict(X[, sample_weight]) - Predict the closest cluster each sample in X test belongs to.

Comment: But how would K-means work for something which has more than 2 coordinates i.e. x and y coordinates? I would like to find the similar player based on a number of factors (6, or 7) Also, in your example, what is the use of the `X - Numpy array`? Is that the training set?

Comment: yes of course it can be applyed to your dataset. Please attach your dataset in json, csv or any convertable format .

Comment: if you could tell me your email id, I could mail it to you. However, I'd still very much like to know the methodology(more than the end product itself) specifically, how to apply K-means to some set like this.

Comment: About methodology you can  read here https://bigdata-madesimple.com/possibly-the-simplest-way-to-explain-k-means-algorithm/